# Blazor component inheritance

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

Hi I'm a new Blazor user, anybody can give me an insight on how to do this on Blazor by just using inline-component without need to override the `BuildRenderTree` method.

The idea is to create a base component (we call it `Component.razor` and it's abstract, inheriting `ComponentBase`) that always render this HTML tag:

```
<div id="@id" class="component @class" state="@state"></div>
```

The base component always have id (an auto-increment) and state variable (for component state like enabled, disabled, etc.)

Then for example we can inherit that Component into Button via `@Inherits` Component, but inside `Button.razor` itself only have this inline HTML:

```
<div class="label">@buttonText</div>
```

But because Button inherit Component, the resulting HTML will be:

```
<div id="123" class="component button" state="1">
    <div class="label">Submit</div>
</div>
```

Notice that the Button will also add "button" class name into the parent div.
And the inheritance can continue as needed for example Component --> Button --> `MultiSelectButton`, etc.

Please advise, Thanks a lot

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is, how to do that using Blazor, as what I stated on the first paragraph on my post.

Comment: Two things came into the scene: *@Body* and *@ChildContent.*

*@Body* is for Layout. Is there a way to make a Component having it's internal Layout? 

*@ChildContent* seems to works the-other-way-around, which is parent modified the content of the children, while here, I need the children to modified the parent's content. 

Or is there something I don't know/misunderstood about both *@Body* and  *@ChildContent* usage? please advise.. 

thanks a lot

Comment: If you're using razor syntax to create a component, composition is preferred over inheritance in such a situation: Simply employ a `@ChildContent` parameter and use `<Component><button>@ButtonText</button></Component>` will make it.

Comment: @itminus But how about the component id? so the id will rely on the Component, while Button don't have any id nor inherit from Component? it's only a layout/composition then.

Comment: @LoekitoMulyadi It depends on how you design the id. If you need an auto-increment id, just add add such a property, you don't need expose it as a parameter. Otherwise, create a public property parameter . Personally, I would suggest the 2nd way as it would be more easy to be tested.